# ANTLR4: How to parse a WKT polygon string?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANLTR4 in java and I could parse a WKT polygon string like this

```
polygon((20 30, 30 40, 50 60, 20 30))
```

with this Lexer:

```
POLYGON: ('polygon'|'POLYGON')'(('[0-9:,-.eTZ" ]+'))';
```

because the numbers inside polygon(( )) can be datetime or float then it contains some characters.

However, I couldn't parse a polygon with inner polygon like this

```
polygon((20 30, 30 40, 50 60, 20 30), (20 30, 30 40, 50 60, 20 30), (20 30, 30 40, 50 60, 20 30))
```

when I tried to add () in Lexer, e.g:

```
POLYGON: ('polygon'|'POLYGON')'(('[0-9:,-.eTZ" \(\)]+'))';
```

Java throws exception, cannot find ")" with .

What can I do to make ANTLR4 can parse polygon((), (), (), ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer should only define the basic building blocks of the language. Polygon, list, etc. should be defined as parser rules.

Something like this should get you started:

```
grammar WKT;

parse
 : polygon EOF
 ;

polygon
 : POLYGON '(' ( points ( ',' points )* )? ')'
 ;

points
 : '(' ( value value ( ',' value value )* )? ')'
 ;

value
 : INT
 | FLOAT
 | DATE_TIME
 ;

POLYGON
 : [pP] [oO] [lL] [yY] [gG] [oO] [nN]
 ;

INT
 : DIGITS
 ;

FLOAT
 : DIGITS '.' DIGITS
 ;

DATE_TIME
 : D D D D '-' D D '-' D D 'T' D D ':' D D ':' D D [+-] D D ':' D D
 | D D D D '-' D D '-' D D 'T' D D ':' D D ':' D D 'Z'
 | D D D D D D D D 'T' D D D D D D 'Z'
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

fragment DIGITS
 : D+
 ;

fragment D
 : [0-9]
 ;
```

The following input: `POLYGON ((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10), (20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))` will be parsed as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that you shouldn't do it with just a lexer.  You should use your lexer to split into symbols; e.g. `'polygon'`, `'('`, `')'`, `','`, `<number>`, `<date>` and so on.  Then implement a grammar to deal with the large scale syntax; e.g.

```
<polygon> ::= 'polygon' '(' <list> ')'

<list> ::= '(' ')' |
           '(' <element> ( ',' <element> ) * ')'

<element> ::= <number> | <date>
```

(The meta-syntax I'm using is sort of EBNF ....)

The problems with using just a regex-based lexer with no grammar are:

- the regex is hard to read / hard to validate
- you don't get a parse tree
- you don't get any meaningful parser errors
- the more complicated the regex is, the more likely you are to run into performance issues; e.g. https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html